# How to boost performance of react application when you have many components in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, testing

It is clear that improving performance of application is depends.
However, I think there are some cases that you can imporove your application.
In my case I have replaced my similar components to HOC.
Any other suggestions ?

Comment: Use Svelte https://svelte.dev/

Comment: Do you have stateful component or use redux? Do you use pure components? [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58192552/1641941) is an example of how to optimize a list of items to be pure components. As a rule of thumb you never do `someProp={{new:'reference'}}` or `someEvent={new=>reference}` because even if your components are pure you would cause re renders and especially with event handlers the virtual dom compare will fail and cause a dom re render.

Comment: any other suggestions ?

Answer (score 3):

Use React.PureComponent. It prevents from unnecessary re-render, but be careful, PureComponent has potential [pitfalls](https://blog.shakacode.com/react-purecomponent-pitfalls-d057882f4b6e).

Comment: One of the pitfalls is embarrassingly bad: `fail to render due to mutating state or props?` The items example with stateful component can be [updated to use functional components with hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58192552/1641941) and having a descent container presentational seperation.  Premature Optimization is often used as an excuse not to write well structured code; like using containers that use reselect.

Answer (score 1):

One of the key point in performance would be the size of JS to be parsed and the number of DOM operations which are made by the same.

> With exponential growth in the number of components, LOC will grow with it.

Primary solutions recommended to it would be to

1. Load your components on demand with code-splitting and dynamic imports
2. Batch your DOM operations / dispatch if using redux
3. Use PureComponents
4. HOC's

Answer (score 1):

If you are developing your web apps on Chrome, its Developer tools has a section called **Audits**.

> The audits are run for many scenarios like image loading, no-JS support, no internet, time for 1st meaningful paint etc. It gives you a performance score at the end.

Run your React app, open Developer Tools and Go to 'Audits'. Choose the target platform (Mobile/Desktop) and run the Audit.

In the end, you will see a list of things that can be improved in your App. Very handy tool.